# Obtain depth(z) from infrared camera view Kinect V2

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using the Xbox One Kinect (V2) to grab the infrared camera view, I then do some processing with that frame. From that I'm given an x,y coordinate in the infrared view. **I would like to know how I would go about finding the depth(z) of that x,y value.** I've played with coordinate mapper, but can't quite figure it out; if that's even the right thing to be using!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of depth-frame and infared-frame have the same imagesize you could just get the z value from your depth frame.

Just look in the samples how to copy the depth-frame to an `byte[]`.

Afterwards this would help you:

```
double depth=(double)depthPixels[_xPos+_yPos*_width];
```